# How can I incorporate a GitHub gist into my Codepen project?

Tags: javascript, github, gist, codepen

I'm incredibly new to Codepen and coding in general, and I'm trying to figure out how to link to [a really big file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Rusty25/85de21b0626bb057beadf0f6009867bd/raw/29dcb32d861b2234329813f057b62c7a3b0016f9/tenmilliondigits.js)  in Codepen. I want to use the variable pieIsGood from my GitHub gist in my Javascript in Codepen, but I have no idea how to go about doing that.

Some lovely StackOverflow user gave me a solution that involved linking to another Codepen project, but the problem is that Codepen only allows you to store a certain amount of data, and that amount is way less than I need.

Can you help me figure out how to incorporate my gist into my Codepen project? Thanks for any help!

[Link to my Codepen project:](http://codepen.io/Random_Pseudonym/pen/EWvdge)

```
ignore this
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use ajax:

```js
const url = '//gist.githubusercontent.com/Rusty25/a18f99e0e0a2c42662cc0746b71a5f00/raw/86e4fce24116005f2748aeacdb5e94624937eb31/pi_digits.json';

fetch(url).then(response => {
  response.json().then(obj => {
    console.log(obj.pi.slice(0,10000));
  });
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
.as-console-row-code{word-break:break-all}
```

See it on CodePen: http://codepen.io/jrunning/pen/jBjVjd?editors=0011

The above uses the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), but you can use XMLHTTPRequest or jQuery's `$.ajax` or whatever you prefer.